# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

Tags: java, selenium

**Code:**

```
public void Test2() throws Exception{ 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
driver.findElement(By.id("cboMenu")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cboMenu/option[3]")).click();
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"cboMenu"}
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'venu-PC', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 0f859bed-35df-4eba-a472-3bc2efec4814
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: Which element you are trying to Locate? Can you provide more details?

Comment: public void Test2() throws Exception{
  Thread.sleep(5000);
   driver.findElement(By.id("cboMenu")).click();   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cboMenu/option[3]")).click();

Comment: I have posted Answer please check the xpath, If still does not works then can you show the HTML code of the element which we are trying to detect by xpath or complete error message

Comment: Can you please add the relevant html code snippet please ?

Answer (score 8):

Please use explicit wait instead of the Thread.sleep(5000), like in the next example.
It will provide you much clearer error regarding what you experience.

```
public void Test2() throws Exception{ 
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("cboMenu")))
    driver.findElement(By.id("cboMenu")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cboMenu/option[3]")).click();
}
```

Next, verify your button doesn't appear in different iFrame. If you do, change the iFrame to the one you element inside:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("IFRAME_ID");
```

The IFRAME_ID is taken from the DOM:

```
<iframe id="IFRAME_ID">
```

You can next change `visibilityOfElementLocated` to `presenceOfElementLocated`, that will verify that an element is present on the DOM but does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. It can be good clue to know if your webDriver is in the correct scope with the button you try to click.

Additional tip - scroll the button you want to click on into view. Thats could be also the reason to failure.

```
//element is WebElement    
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is solved my issue :)

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.openstream.cueme.services.workbench");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElementById("userId").sendKeys("sysadmin");
        driver.findElementById("CuemePassword").sendKeys("MMNext13#");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation so that it will help to understand.

Comment: Actually the web-view was not ready while executing the tests. when i put Thread.sleep(10000); it works fine .

driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.openstream.cueme.services.workbench");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElementById("userId").sendKeys("sysadmin");
driver.findElementById("CuemePassword").sendKeys("MMNext13#");
One clarification while automating the below scenario

Comment: Please use `edit` link to add the additional information instead putting it into comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public void Test2() throws Exception{
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.findElement(By.id("cboMenu")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cboMenu']/option[3]")).click();
```

Comment: Is there any change in your answer and the question's code?